# Drop and create postgresql db in jenkins

Tags: postgresql, jenkins

I have a jenkins and separate postgresql db. During the build there are some tests utilizing this db. What is the best way to drop and create fresh db instance at the start of each jenkins job?

Comment: which unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: I am using junit. If you wanted to suggest transactional tests (with rollback) to remove the need to drop DB, it won't be possible since the tests can't be changed to transactional (due to volume and way the processing is implemented).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best way, but i found good enough solution. Just added postgresql-client (psql) to the machine which is running jenkins and added simple sh command to jenkins pipeline to drop and recreate db:

```
stage('Clean DB') {
    sh "psql -h <db_host> -p <db_port> -U <db_user> -d <admin_db> -c \"DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS <db_name_to_drop>\""
    sh "psql -h <db_host> -p <db_port> -U <db_user> -d <admin_db> -c \"CREATE DATABASE <db_name_to_create>\""
}
... other stages like build etc...
```

Since you can't drop the DB instace you are currently logged into, i am connecting to "postgres" db which is created by postgres by default (parameter "admin_db" in the command above) and from there i drop and create the required DB. Also remember that due to security the password is not entered in the command but is saved in a file on the machine or in the env variable (see psql documentation for more details).